# Rendering object property value only if it exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects like this getting mapped and rendered.

```
const items = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'name',
    comment: 'text',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'name',
  },
  etc...
]
```

```
var hasComment = items.some(item => item.hasOwnProperty('comment'));

const card = items.map(item => 
        <div key={item.id}>
            <ul className="detail">
                <li>{item.name}</li>
                {hasComment ? <li>{item.comment}</li> : ''}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I want the comment to be displayed depending of the property of each individual object. I googled the above solution but as soon as **any** object of my array has this property it gets displayed for all, leaving some empty list items. The comment on each individual item should only be rendered, if the object actually has this property.

Hopefully it's clear what I mean.

Comment: hasComment returns true if any of the items has a comment.  You could lose that entirely and instead of `hasComment ?` just use `item.comment ?`

Comment: You're my hero, James! Does exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the property check inside a `.filter` before mapping to render:

```
const card = items
  .filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('comment')
  .map(item => {
    // ...
```